# ReactJS and Boolean Values

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, boolean

While learning React I came upon the finding that for some reason it doesn't do booleans the way I'm used to and I cannot seem to understand it.

I've tried a couple of methods to fix it but without success and I'm basically about to give up on React. jQuery is much much easier for me.

I understand that React saves the false value as a string to state and then interprets it as truthy. But I haven't managed to find a way to either save it as boolean or convert it to boolean.

Has React even heard of Boolean?!?!

Have a look at the fiddle and please tell me what I'm missing...or at least point me in the right direction. Been losing my mind on this for a whole day.

https://jsfiddle.net/nicholas_cb/btye84j2/14/

```
function Options(props) {

    /* TRIED TO FIX IT THIS WAY SO AS TO SET CHECKD VALUES TO BOOLEAN INSTEAD OF STRING AND CHANGING THE CHECKED VALUE TO LOCAL VARIABLES -- OBVIOUSLY DIDN'T WORK... x_X

    let optionValue1 = (props.optionValue1 == true);
    let optionValue2 = (props.optionValue2 == true);

    */

    console.log("Options received: optionValue1 = " + props.optionValue1 + " optionValue2 = " + props.optionValue2);
        let result = "Options received: optionValue1 = " + props.optionValue1 + " optionValue2 = " + props.optionValue2;
    
    return (
    <div>
    <br/>
    <label>{result}</label>
    <br/><br/>
    <label>Option One</label><input name="optionValue1" type="checkbox" checked={props.optionValue1} onChange={props.handleChange}/>
        <label>Option Two</label><input name="optionValue2" type="checkbox" checked={props.optionValue2} onChange={props.handleChange}/>
      </div>
    )
    
}

class Form extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props)
   }

    render() {
    if(this.props.optionValue1 == true && this.props.optionValue2 == true) {
    console.log("TRUE/TRUE");
    return (
     <Options 
       optionValue1 = {this.props.optionValue1}
       optionValue2 = {this.props.optionValue2}
       handleChange = {this.props.handleChange}
     />
    )
    }
    
        if(this.props.optionValue1 == false && this.props.optionValue2 == true) {
    console.log("FALSE/TRUE");
    return (
     <Options 
       optionValue1 = {this.props.optionValue1}
       optionValue2 = {this.props.optionValue2}
       handleChange = {this.props.handleChange}
     />
    )
    }
    
        if(this.props.optionValue1 == false && this.props.optionValue2 == false) {
    console.log("FALSE/FALSE");
    return (
     <Options 
       optionValue1 = {this.props.optionValue1}
       optionValue2 = {this.props.optionValue2}
       handleChange = {this.props.handleChange}
     />
    )
    }
    
        if(this.props.optionValue1 == true && this.props.optionValue2 == false) {
    console.log("TRUE/FALSE");
    return (
     <Options 
       optionValue1 = {this.props.optionValue1}
       optionValue2 = {this.props.optionValue2}
       handleChange = {this.props.handleChange}
     />
    )
    }
    
    console.log("Matched no case.");
    return (
      <Options 
       optionValue1 = {this.props.optionValue1}
       optionValue2 = {this.props.optionValue2}
       handleChange = {this.props.handleChange}
     />
    )
  }

  
}

class FormContainer extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    optionValue1: true,
    optionValue2: true,
  }

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

}

    handleChange(event) {

        if(event.target.type == 'checkbox'){
            console.log("Checkbox changing: " + event.target.name);
            console.log("New value: " + event.target.checked);
            
                event.target.value = event.target.checked;
                        
        }

        const {name, value} = event.target
        
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <Form
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        optionValue1={this.state.optionValue1}
        optionValue2={this.state.optionValue2}
      />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FormContainer />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I've output all cases to console such as TRUE/TRUE, FALSE/TRUE, etc. It's also surprising to me that for some reason it comes across the matched none case? What's up with that? Where's that coming from? If it interprets it as truthy/falsy shouldn't it always match one of the cases?

Thanks

Comment: React is just a javascript framework. It's javascript. It saves in state whatever you tell it to save to state, so if boolean values are getting converted/coerced/etc into strings it is your code doing that. It's also why you should very nearly *always* use `===` for comparisons instead of `==`.

Comment: for every case `if ()` you are returning same output. Why?

Comment: The `if` conditional tests also don't match the console log output. In JS you also don't generally directly compare to `true` or `false`, but use the fact that the variables being used in the conditionals are *already* booleans, i.e. `true` or `false`.

Comment: @DrewReese That's true thanks for pointing that out. My bad...was kind of in a hurry and messed up the conditions a bit. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just spent my 10 minutes so you don't get disappointed from React. It's way better than jQuery

First of all, use some better tools than jsfiddle. it is not for react development, it is just for code which can be written badly in one file. Use [`Codesandbox.io`](https://codesandbox.io)

Check this sandbox and let me know if still there is confusion

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-bassi-l7pg8?file=/src/App.js

What you are doing wrong is that you are using state values to check/uncheck checkboxes but in `handleChange` callback

```
handleChange(event) {
        if(event.target.type == 'checkbox'){
            // This is wrong, don't change dom yourself if you are using controlled component
           // https://medium.com/@AndrewBonner2/controlled-components-in-react-920f3e795d87
            event.target.value = event.target.checked; 
        }
        // const {name, value} = event.target;
        // SHould be 
        // const { name, checked } = event.target;
        this.setState({
            // [name]: value
            // SHould be
             [name]: checked 
        })
    }
```

Comment: That just looks like OPs code now running in a codesandbox. What is different? How is this an answer? Is there a second of all?

Comment: OP was assigning `e.target.value = e.target.checked` something like that, that was wrong, I fixed that

Comment: He was using state and then again setting values using `e.target`

Comment: @DrewReese Look into OP's `handleChnage` callback

Comment: An answer should explain that then. I only asked because the behavior in the UI didn't seem any different.

Comment: @DrewReese the codesandbox link is probably just to show the better fiddle software with the original code without any changes. Just to make it clear for anyone else reading this.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Thank you man. Really enlightened me on this. Even though I was changing the actual value of the input with the e.target.value = e.target.checked for some reason it wasn't registering as such in my brain even though I know I shouldn't do that in react. My bad. But the real eye opener was the e.target.checked. That's all that's actually needed. 

I should have stored the checked value to the checked state. And this fact means I need to look deeper into this state thing to avoid something like this in the future. 

Thanks man.Life saver.Valuable 10 min. I'm sticking to react. :))

Comment: I changed the code to 

`
if(event.target.type == 'checkbox'){
    const {name, checked} = event.target
    this.setState({  [name]: checked  })
}else{
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({  [name]: value  })
}
`

Comment: Awesome, Thinking in React is bit different than old jquery style. I still see people using window.addEventListerners for click and then updating dom using query selector. Watch more videos and you start thinking in React way. Here is an awesome series for React beginners https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPT3bFIwJYA&list=PL55RiY5tL51oyA8euSROLjMFZbXaV7skS

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Quite different indeed. Thanks for the link I'll run through it.